# Coloring 4-connected triangulations with 4 odd vertices

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a triangulation (maximal planar graph) which is 4-connected and has exactly four odd vertices, (perhaps none adjacent to each other, but at least two non adjacent to each other), and let $x$, $y$ be two of the odd vertices, non adjacent to each other. I wish to prove the following.

**Statement** $G$ can be 4-colored in such a way that $x$, $y$ are colored with different colors.

Is this statement true or false, and why?  How might one try to prove this?

Comment: I'm very lazy, so I'm not actually going to do this, but you could: use [plantri](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/) to generate some 4-connected triangulations, then use use [igraph](https://igraph.org/) to pick out the ones with the right vertex degrees and check if $\chi(G+xy) \le 4$ for all of them. This would either show that the statement is false, or make it very likely that it's true.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I have an answer to this, will post it right up in some minutes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Misha Lavrov's suggestion we found counterexamples.  Here is a graph with 14 vertices, 4 of them odd, call them $u, v, x, y$, such that $u, v$ must be colored the same, and $x, y$ must also be colored the same in any 4 coloring.  In the picture below, $u, v$ are the topmost two yellow vertices, and $x, y$ are the rightmost two green vertices.  I still don't know if the statement I was trying to prove will be true if we add the condition that the four odd vertices must be pairwise non adjacent.  The graph was generated with plantri by T. Jensen, and the coloring property was checked with igraph by EGME.  Please note that although not rendered as a planar graph , the graph is planar.

[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

The four odd vertices must all have a different color or have pairswise the same color or the four odd vertices can have the same color if no odd vertex is adjacent to another odd one.

Lemma: the degreesums of idem colored vertices in a proper 4colored maximal planar graph must all have the same parity, all odd or all even.

Proof:
Let $C,M,Y$ and $K$ be the vertexcolors and $d(C), d(M), d(Y)$ and $d(K)$ their degreesum.
Color the edges between the properly colored vertices as follow, (with $x''$ if adjacent to vertexcolor $K$):

$CM=b' ; YK=b'' ; CY=g' ;  MK=g'' ; MY=r'   ; CK=r''$

Every triangle in the graph with $v$ vertices has now a red, green and bleu edge. E.g. the edges of a $CMY$ triange are then $r',g',b'$, and for a $CYK$ triangle we get $r'',g',b''$. Let $n_x$ be the number of edges with color $x$.  As we have $2(v-2)$ triangles we have then $v-2$ red, green and bleu edges or $n_x=n_{x''}+n_{x'}=v-2$.
The degreesums pro color are then
$d(C)=n_{r''}+n_{g'}+n_{b'}$
$d(M)=n_{r'}+n_{g''}+n_{b'}$
$d(Y)=n_{r'}+n_{g'}+n_{b''}$
$d(K)=n_{r''}+n_{g''}+n_{b''}$
Making the sum of two gives:

$d(C)+d(M)=(n_{r''}+n_{r'})+(n_{g'}+n_{g''})+2n_{b'}=2((v-2)+n_{b'})$
$d(C)+d(Y)=(n_{r''}+n_{r'})+2n_{g'}+(n_{b'}+n_{b''})=2((v-2)+n_{g'})$
$...$

or the sum of the degreesums for **any** two vertexcolors is even.
So the degreesum for the vertices with the same color must ALL be even or odd.
[Vertex-edge relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxsPc.png)

Conclusion: If the degreesums are odd, all four odd vertices have a different color ($C,M,Y,K,$) and if the degreesums are even all odd vertices can have the same color (e.g.$C,C,C,C$) or we have two different pairs with the same color (e.g.$C,C,M,M$). In the latter case 4 of the 6 pairs of these odd vertices have a different color. Which ones? Who knows?

For short: **You can't have X,Y,U,U.**

If two odd vertices have a different color, the two oher ones have also **a** different color $(X,Y; X,Y) or (X,Y;U,V)$.
If two odd vertices have the same color, the two other ones have also **a** same color $(X,X;X,X) or (X,X;YY)$
[this 3 cases for small graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeMQm.gif)

PS: Thanks to SASWATA SHANNIGRAHI who observed the property of the lemma in 2005 on sci.math.

Comment: Where can I find a simpler proof for this Lemma?

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Please format your math using MathJax. Your lack of MathJax formatting is almost certainly why you are being downvited. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @C-RAM : Done, but how can one give more space between formula's on the same line?

Comment: Which formula are you trying to fix?

Comment: @C-RAM: This one, with two spaces instead of ";".   CM=b′;YK=b′′; CY=g′;MK=g′′;MY=r′;CK=r′′